# hot to get value of radio button in group

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

how to get value of radio button from 2 different groups (DIVs: step-1 & step-2)?? actually i have 5, but it will be the same story.

**Initialising**

```
        var a1Id;
        var a2Id; 
        var a3Id;
        var a4Id; 
        var a5Id;
        var a6Id; 

a1Id = questionaireResult.questions[0].answers[0].id; (value of id = 1)
            document.getElementById('antwort1fuerFrage1').value = a1Id;

 a2Id = questionaireResult.questions[0].answers[1].id; (value of id = 2)
                document.getElementById('antwort2fuerFrage1').value = a2Id;

and so on for 3,4,5, and 6...
```

**JQUERY** hier i want to read Value of selected Radio buttons. doing it for each group

```
var selected = $("#step-1 input[type='radio']:checked");
                if (selected.length > 0) {
                    var answerIDQ1 = $('input[class=group1]:checked').val();
                }

                var selected = $("#step-2 input[type='radio']:checked");
                if (selected.length > 0) {
                    var answerIDQ2 = $('input[class=group2]:checked').val();
                }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="step-1">
                <h2 class="StepTitle">
                    <label style="font-weight: bold; color: #662819;" id="frage1"></label>
                </h2>
                <br />

                <input type="radio" class="group1" name="group1" id="frage1antwort1" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
                <label id="antwort1fuerFrage1"></label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="radio"  class="group1" name="group1" id="frage1antwort2" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
                <label id="antwort2fuerFrage1"></label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="radio"  class="group1" name="group1" id="frage1antwort3" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
                <label id="antwort3fuerFrage1"></label>
            </div>

            <div id="step-2">
                <h2 class="StepTitle">
                    <label style="font-weight: bold; color: #662819;" id="frage2"></label>
                </h2>
                <br />

                <input type="radio"  class="group2" name="group2" id="frage2antwort1" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
                <label id="antwort1fuerFrage2"></label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="radio"  class="group2" name="group2" id="frage2antwort2" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
                <label id="antwort2fuerFrage2"></label>
                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="radio"  class="group2" name="group2" id="frage2antwort3" value="" onmousedown="this.__chk = this.checked" onclick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
                <label id="antwort3fuerFrage2"></label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why is the attribute of value "" when you are calling the val()?

Comment: what do you mean by `Initialising`?

Comment: because iam adding value other way like this: a1Id = questionaireResult.questions[0].answers[0].id;document.getElementById('antwort1fuerFrage1').value = a1Id;

Comment: so you want iterate through a loop and find the values of all groups

Comment: something like that, but i cant do it... :(

Comment: It will be better if you can go with a object like `{answerIDQ1: x, answerIDQ2: y}` will that do

Comment: also you will be able to add a class to the `<div id="step-1">` element right

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you please show me it in code??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38113/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-ragims-ragimovs)

Comment: checkout http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GDhu4/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var step1=$("#step-1 input:radio[name='group1']:checked").val();
 var step2= $("#step-2 input:radio[name='group2']:checked").val();
alert(step1+' '+ step2);
```

Comment: your code workinf if iam staticly entering something in value of radio button. maybe iam doing it wrong like this: document.getElementById('antwort1fuerFrage1').value = a1Id;?

Comment: you can set the value of label like this
`$('#antwort1fuerFrage1').text(a1Id);`

or

`$('#<%=antwort1fuerFrage1.ClientID%>').html(a1Id);`

Comment: trying with: $('#antwort1fuerFrage1').text(a1Id);....instead of value=1, i am getting here   var selected = $("#step-1 input[type='radio']:checked");
                if (selected.length > 0) {
                    var answerIDQ1 = $('input[name=group1]:checked').val();
                }   --------------> value="on", but why on????

Comment: I ran your code again,however i'm not getting any such value,instead i'm getting **""** as you haven't provided any value in radio button.